# How to lists all variables in java classes which are mutable in that class

Tags: java, static

I have a list of java classes approx 200. I need to prepare a list of variables (specifically static and non final) whose value is getting modified/mutated in the java classes. In order to prepare list of all static and non final variables I used reflection.

But I am not sure how can I check if every single variable is mutated in the class or not, without opening each and every file manually.

```
class ClassVO{
    private static final String name;
    private String fieldName;
    private static double single=0.01;
    private static double value;

   void calculate(){
     value = value*0.25;
   }
}
```

In above example "value" variable needs to be returned.
Are there any tools available which can be used to achieve this kinds of work? Please share.

Comment: Sounds a tedious task. Take into account even if a field is final it can be mutated. For instance a final Collection when you add/remove an element. So apart of the modifiers, you should check that each instance is immutable or not.

Comment: @Ezequiel and even if the collection itself disallows adding, setting or removing, the elements can be mutable.

Comment: So, does it means I have to do it manually only. because those file list is big and I was thinking some tools like PMD can solve it , but not sure about its use.

Comment: @Chabukswar i have added an answer hope that helps u

Comment: @Ezequiel i have provided a sample workout can u please have a look ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hard way to do so , I have used Apache bcel library which can load JavaClass file. 
i.e. `bcel-6.0.jar`
Sample input class:-

```
public class Test {
    private static final String name = "";
    private String fieldName;
    private static String  single = "notMutable";
    private static double value;
    private String random;

    public void print(){
        value = value*0.25;
        fieldName = "foo";
        String sample =single+"1";
    }
}
```

Code to check reference of variable (static/instance) in a method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> usedVariables = new ArrayList<String>();
            JavaClass  javaClass =  Repository.lookupClass(Test.class);
            for(Method m: javaClass.getMethods()) {
                String code = m.getCode().toString();
                String[] codes = code.split("\\r?\\n");
                if(!m.getName().matches("<clinit>|<init>")) {
                    for(String c: codes) {
                        if(c.contains(javaClass.getClassName()+".") && (c.contains("putstatic") || c.contains("putfield"))) {
                            System.out.println("Class static/Instant mutable variable Used inside method @ --> "+c);
                            String variableName = c.substring(c.indexOf(javaClass.getClassName()));
                            usedVariables.add(variableName.split(":")[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result --> " +usedVariables);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Class static/Instant mutable variable Used inside method @ --> 7:    putstatic      Test.value:D (30)
Class static/Instant mutable variable Used inside method @ --> 13:   putfield       Test.fieldName:Ljava/lang/String; (36)
Result --> [Test.value, Test.fieldName]
```

Though inside the method **`print`** static Variable value and single is used but the variable `single` value is not changed while `value` is changed
**hence the output only shows mutable fields** ie.

```
Result --> [Test.value, Test.fieldName]
```

Comment: its worked for me. Thank you!! I can take reference of this code. I was not aware of Apache bcel library.

Comment: @Chabukswar if u feel that answer helped u , u can upvote also.